# CoreData objects not saved between screens

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a screen that holds a `UITableView`, in this screen I have an array of `NSManagedObjects`. It's working just fine, but as I try move to another screen (click on a specific cell, and push a new screen), then return to the same `UITableView` screen, all the objects got lost.

What does it means? I try to print the array of the `NSManagedObjects` and it's fine, all the objects there, but as I print the description of each object, I get `nil` from all the object attributes.

Someone knows whats the cause of it? I don't know why but it worked just fine 12 hours ago, but now it's all messed up and I don't have a clue what have I done.

Thanks in advance!

Save method:

```
- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Context saved!");
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I save the objects:

```
NSDictionary *response = responseObject;
if ([[response valueForKey:@"status"] rangeOfString:@"ok"].location != NSNotFound)
{
   NSArray *data = [response objectForKey:@"data"];
   if (data.count != 0)
   {
       if (page.integerValue == 0) {
           [[DownloadData sharedData] deleteAllObjectsFromEntityName:@"DbHomeCuisine"];
           [[DownloadData sharedData] deleteAllObjectsFromEntityName:@"DbHomeCategory"];
           [[DownloadData sharedData] deleteAllObjectsFromEntityName:@"DbHomeDish"];
       }

       NSMutableArray *homePageObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:data.count];
       for (NSDictionary *object in data)
       {
           NSNumber *type = [object objectForKey:@"type"];
           switch (type.integerValue) {
               case 1:
               {
                   NSDictionary *content = [object objectForKey:@"content"];
                   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[MainDb sharedDb] managedObjectContext];
                   DbHomeCuisine *homeCuisine = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DbHomeCuisine" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                   NSInteger cuisineId = [[content valueForKey:@"cuisine_id"] integerValue];
                   homeCuisine.cuisine = [self gCuisineWithCuisineId:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:cuisineId]];
                   NSInteger count = [[content valueForKey:@"count"] integerValue];
                   homeCuisine.count = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:count];
                   homeCuisine.type = type;
                   [homePageObjects addObject:homeCuisine];
               }
                   break;

               case 2:
               {
                   NSDictionary *content = [object objectForKey:@"content"];
                   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[MainDb sharedDb] managedObjectContext];
                   DbHomeCategory *homeCategory = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DbHomeCategory" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                   NSInteger categoryId = [[content valueForKey:@"category_id"] integerValue];
                   homeCategory.category = [self gCategoryWithCategoryId:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:categoryId]];
                   NSInteger count = [[content valueForKey:@"count"] integerValue];
                   homeCategory.count = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:count];
                   homeCategory.type = type;
                   [homePageObjects addObject:homeCategory];
               }
                   break;

               case 3:
               {
                   NSDictionary *content = [object objectForKey:@"content"];
                   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[MainDb sharedDb] managedObjectContext];
                   DbHomeDish *homeDish = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DbHomeDish" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                   homeDish.dishId          = [self gInt:content forKey:@"dish_id"];
                   homeDish.headline        = [AppUtils checkForEmptyValue:[content valueForKey:@"title"]];
                   homeDish.text            = [AppUtils checkForEmptyValue:[content valueForKey:@"description"]];
                   homeDish.cuisineId       = [self gInt:content forKey:@"cuisine_id"];
                   homeDish.cuisine         = [self gCuisineWithCuisineId:homeDish.cuisineId];
                   homeDish.creationDate    = [AppUtils checkForEmptyValue:[content valueForKey:@"creation_time"]];
                   homeDish.userId          = [self gInt:content forKey:@"user_id"];
                   homeDish.longitude       = [self gDouble:content forKey:@"lng"];
                   homeDish.latitude        = [self gDouble:content forKey:@"lat"];
                   homeDish.lastPromoteDate = [AppUtils checkForEmptyValue:[content valueForKey:@"last_promote_time"]];
                   homeDish.price           = [self gInt:content forKey:@"price"];
                   homeDish.currency        = [AppUtils checkForEmptyValue:[content valueForKey:@"currency"]];
                   homeDish.countryName     = [AppUtils checkForEmptyValue:[content valueForKey:@"country_name"]];
                   homeDish.baseCurrency    = [self gFloat:content forKey:@"base_currency"];
                   homeDish.exchangeRate    = [self gFloat:content forKey:@"exchange_rate"];
                   homeDish.countryIsoCode  = [AppUtils checkForEmptyValue:[content valueForKey:@"country_iso_code"]];
                   homeDish.mainPhoto       = [AppUtils checkForEmptyValue:[content valueForKey:@"main_photo"]];
                   homeDish.like            = [self gLikeWithDishId:homeDish.dishId];
                   homeDish.profileImageURL = [AppUtils checkForEmptyValue:[content valueForKey:@"profile_img_url"]];
                   homeDish.likeCount       = [self gInt:content forKey:@"likes"];
                   homeDish.type            = type;
                   [homePageObjects addObject:homeDish];
               }
                   break;

               default:
                   break;
           }
       }

       //   @@log -- Save data to core data and device
       //
       //
       [[MainDb sharedDb] saveContext];

       if (success) {
           success(operation, homePageObjects);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Show the code for the data mods, save and UI transitions

Comment: @Wain there are 15 entities in my core data model... How can I show them? The save is the base CoreData save. The transition of UI is a simple Push from UINavigationController.

Comment: And how do you get back? We don't need all entities, but a sample of how you update and save the model, then query it again. The transition part is more about what you come back to. At the moment you question is a broad 'guess what I might have done wrong' as is as such unanswerable...

Comment: @Wain The transitions are all normal Push and Pop methods. Another important thing that I forgot, as I pop the screen and returns to the UITableView and it shows me the nil objects, I got the same 3 objects that I saw before I push the controller, as I scroll the UITableView controller down I got those 3 all over again.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are querying your database in the `viewDidLoad:` method? Or similar? The code you've posted looks fine: what are you logging to the debugger? It seems that your managed objects are getting released.

Comment: @Wain At start I'm going to the web service to get the objects, check my question I updated it with the code of the insert of the objects.. Thanks man.

Comment: Is the response from the web service on a background thread?

Comment: @Wain No, but it doesn't matter, because it's working fine. When I push and pop back, I don't get the data back from the server, the data is already there before I push and when I pop back it's gone.

Comment: I think I found what's wrong.. Before I push, I've checked the core data to see how many objects of DbHomeDish there are inside and I see that it's fine, like it should be. Then I push the screen and when I pop it back, I check the core data for the count of the objects and I found there is only 1 object inside, the one I push into, all the others are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously, you should consider refactoring using a `NSFetchedResultsController`. Start from the template provided in Xcode (New Project -> Master/Detail -> check Core Data, the code is in `MasterViewController.m`).

I strongly discourage loading Core Data objects into an array to be displayed in a table view. Your problem is typical for such a setup, and you will run into memory and performance issues eventually as well.